# Get query string value in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, query-string

I am having URL as http://example.com/callback?code=abcd

I need to fetch value of code.
Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const Callback = () => {
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hiii");
    
}, []);

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        Callback
    </React.Fragment>
);
};

export default Callback;
```

Please confirm how can I fetch that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your link not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best way is to use the `useParams` hook because you have a functional component. Read from [the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) as the following:

> `useParams` returns an object of key/value pairs of URL parameters. Use it to access `match.params` of the current `<Route>`.

I would suggest the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const Callback = () => {
   let { code } = useParams()

   console.log({ code });

   return (
      <React.Fragment>
          Callback
      </React.Fragment>
   )
};
```

---

*+1 from documentation:*

> You need to be using React >= 16.8 in order to use any of these hooks!

Answer (score 1):

use this library 'query-string'
and use as

```
import queryString from 'query-string';
```

in constructor

```
  constructor(props) {
    const { location: { search } } = props;
    const parsed = queryString.parse(search);
     this.state = {
      code: parsed.code,
       }
   }
```

hope it will solve your problem !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URLSearchParams interface to fetch the query string of a URL.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const code = queryParams.get("code");
```

Comment: You're forgetting about rendering and useEffect, the question is about React.

Answer (score 0):

First at App.js you should have react-router-dom

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

Then inside switch you can define route parameters like in your case

```
<Route exact path="/callback/:code" component={YourComponentsName} />
```

At the components file you can get the parameters from the props

Functional Component

```
const code = props.match.params.code
```

Class Component

```
 const code = this.props.match.params.code
```

Or next approach

```
const code = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);    

const code = query.get('code')

console.log(code)//abcd
```

Comment: This will not work with the search query param. You need to parse `window.location.search` and that cannot be done with react-router paths

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a hook...

```
useEffect(() => {
  let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  console.log(urlParams.code || "empty");
}, []);
```